# Get data from JSON file to populate dropdown and display other data on select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a .json file with some info and wht I want to do is to populate my dropdown with some of the info and when I select an option from the dropdown, I want to display more info from the .json file.

So far, I have this:

```
[{
  "options": "Option 1 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2"
},
 {
  "options": "Option 2 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2"
},
{
  "options": "Option 3 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2"
},
}]

CSS:

<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style

HTML:

<select id="sel">
   <option value="">Select option</option>
</select>
<div class="box" id="sol"></div>

JS:

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
var url = "devices.json";

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.provider + '">' + value.provider + 
'</option>');
        

  }); 
    });

$("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("#sol").text(optionValue);
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

So, when the user select an option, I want to display some data from the .json file according to the selection.

At the moment, I can just make the value to populate the div, but I want to use data from the .json file.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible if you could share the main response of json file it would be easier to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the json with a http request, you should pass it to the global variable

```js
var url = "devices.json";
let data;
$.getJSON(url, function (_data) {
    data = _data;
/* no other change */
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = "devices.json";

const data = [{
  "options": "Option 1 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1 - 1",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2 - 1"
},
 {
  "options": "Option 2 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1 - 2",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2 - 2"
},
{
  "options": "Option 3 on dropdown",
  "result1": "Text to populate div1 - 3",
  "result2": "Text to populate div2 - 3"
}]
//$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#sel').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value.options + 
'</option>');
        

  }); 
//    });

$("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");

            if(optionValue){
                $("#sol").text(data[optionValue].options);
                $("#div1").text(data[optionValue].result1);
                $("#div2").text(data[optionValue].result2);
                $(".box").show();
                /*
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("#sol").text(optionValue);
                $("." + optionValue).show();
                */
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
   <option value="">Select option</option>
</select>
<div class="box" id="sol"></div>
<div class="box" id="div1"></div>
<div class="box" id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: That works fine, but what if the data is coming from a json file and not hard coded in the html file? how would I populate the data variable with the data from the .json file?

Comment: It seems you are trying to get it with `$.getJSON(url,` in the original code, it should work fine. They are both json objects and the code would work. Let me add to my answer.

Comment: Amazing stuff. @idfurw.